# Chained substitutions of an application in $\lambda$-calculus, e.g. $AB[C/x][D/y]$

Tags: substitution, lambda-calculus

Let $A[C/x]$ denote substitution of $C$ for $x$ in $A$.

Suppose we arrived at the expression $AB[C/x][D/y]$ and we want to manipulate it as follows:

$$
\begin{aligned}
AB[C/x][D/y] &= \Big(\big((AB)[C/x]\big)[D/y]\Big)\\
&= \Big(\big((A[C/x])(B[C/x])\big)[D/y]\Big)\\
&= \Big(\big((A[C/x])[D/y]\big)\big((B[C/x])[D/y]\big)\Big)\\
&= \big(A[C/x][D/y]\big)\big(B[C/x][D/y]\big)\\
\end{aligned}
$$

- Can we perform the above manipulations always?
- Or only if certain conditions hold?

  - such as $x \neq y \text{ and } \big(y \not \in \textsf{FV}(C) \text{ or } x \not \in \textsf{FV}(AB)\big)$ (see below)

---

Here's one way to arrive at $AB[C/x][D/y]$:

$\beta$-reduction is, of course, defined in terms of substitution as:

$$(\lambda x.A)\ C \rightarrow_{\beta} A[C/x]$$

Under certain conditions, we have

$$(\lambda xy.AB)\ C\ D \twoheadrightarrow_{\beta} AB[C/x][D/y]$$

**Proof:**

$$
\begin{aligned}
(\lambda xy.AB)\ C\ D &\rightarrow_{\beta} ((\lambda y.AB)[C/x])\ D\\
&\equiv (\lambda y.(AB[C/x]))\ D &&\text{conditions: } x \neq y \text{ and } \big(y \not \in \textsf{FV}(C) \text{ or } x \not \in \textsf{FV}(AB)\big)\\
&\rightarrow_{\beta} (AB[C/x])[D/y]\\
&\equiv AB[C/x][D/y]
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you described above sounds nothing but *successive* substitutions in lambda calculus and we certainly need some rules for it to be manipulated like you specified as referenced [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Substitution):

> Substitution on terms of the lambda calculus is defined by recursion on the structure of terms, as follows (note: x and y are only variables while M and N are any lambda expression):

> $1. x[x := N] = N \\
> 2. y[x := N] = y, \text{if}~ x ≠ y \\
> 3. (M_1 M_2)[x := N] = (M_1[x := N]) (M_2[x := N]) \\
> 4. (λx.M)[x := N] = λx.M \\
> 5. (λy.M)[x := N] = λy.(M[x := N]), \text{if}~ x ≠ y ~\text{and}~ y ∉ FV(N) \\
> 6. \text{To substitute into an abstraction, it is sometimes necessary to α-convert the expression.}$

> β-reduction is defined in terms of substitution...

So in your first example if both $A,B$ are terms without abstraction, then you can always have $AB[C/x][D/y]=(A[C/x][D/y])(B[C/x][D/y])$ and further possible result may be based on the specific content of $A,B$. For example, if $A$ doesn't contain variable $x$ and $x \neq y$ then your substitution $[C/x]$ will have no effect on $A$. On the other hand, if your expressions have lambda abstraction(s), then you need to match the conditions of any of the rules 4/5/6 above to proceed accordingly.

Finally *successive* substitution is different from *simultaneous* substitution as shown from following example using your notation. If $M ≡ x_1x_2$, then the successive substitution results in $(M[x_1 /x_2])[u/x_1] ≡ [u/x_1 ](x_1x_1) ≡ uu$, while the simultaneous substitution results in $M[x_1 /x_2, u/x_1] ≡ ux_1$.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn’t heard of simultaneous substitution, but the examples clearly show how it’s different from a chain of substitutions.